# How to implement randomize() in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I have ModelSim, so I can't use randomize in my code.

I have to implement randomize() on a transaction class (which extends uvm_sequence_item). How can I do it in verilog?

Comment: I don't understand. If you can do UVM, why can't you do randomize?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you think ModelSim can't do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15439710/modelsim-support-for-sv

Comment: ModelSim doesn't support randomize. Questa does.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  $random . The function is verilog based and might work in modelsim.

```
q = $random(r_seed);
or
q = $random(); //seed is optional
```

Additionally to get random value between 10-110 (range )

```
q = {$random} % (110-10+1) + 10;
```

Or try using

```
$urandom_range(110,10);
$urandom();
```

These are basic randomization constructs . You will have to derive your constraints from these.