# uvm_port_base class derivation correct hierarchy

Tags: uvm

[image]

The above two diagrams are contradicting. Can someone please clarify what is the correct class inheritence for this class? Below mentioned is the link for both in the sequential order

https://www.dvteclipse.com/uvm-1.2_Public_API/uvm_pkg-uvm_port_base.html

Comment: I'm guessing you trying to learn UVM by reading the API. The API is great for understanding the inter-relations, but doesn't do a good job as an introduction or explaining big-picture. I suggest reading [UVM User Guide](http://www.accellera.org/images//downloads/standards/uvm/uvm_users_guide_1.2.pdf) from Accellera. You can also get the UVM source from them and other documentation: http://accellera.org/downloads/standards/uvm/ Other resources: https://verificationacademy.com , http://cluelogic.com , and others listed in my [SO profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1959732?tab=profile)

Comment: Thanks for so many sources

Comment: @Greg does Modelsim have the required environment setup for UVM, to start developing TB?

Comment: [Modelsim support for SV](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15439710/1959732); the short answer is no. From [ModelSim](https://www.mentor.com/products/fpga/verification-simulation/modelsim/)'s product page: "_For advanced verification capabilities such as SystemVerilog **class-based testbench**, functional coverage, and **UVM support**, find out more about our highest performance simulation solution: [Questa](https://www.mentor.com/products/fv/questa/)®_"

Comment: @Greg I have licensed version of Modelsim 10.4b. Does that support UVM, assertions, coverage and program blocks? More specifically I am interested in knowing about UVM support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a little sneaky because both are true. Looking at the source, the first line declare `uvm_port_base`

```
virtual class uvm_port_base #(type IF=uvm_void) extends IF;
```

`uvm_port_base` inherits from `IF`, which is a parameter. Default value of `IF` is `uvm_void`.

For example, many TLM classes override the parameter with another class to extend from. For Example:

```
class uvm_blocking_put_export #(type T=int)
  extends uvm_port_base #(uvm_tlm_if_base #(T,T));
```

`uvm_tlm_if_base` extends form `uvm_if_base_abstract`, which extends from `uvm_report_object`, which extends from `uvm_object`, which extends from `uvm_void`. Basically `uvm_blocking_put_export` still has `uvm_void` as a parent but it also got all the added functionality added by all the other parents. This redirected inheritance is a work around to [multiple inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) challenge for a language that can only support single inheritance<sup>*</sup>.

---

*<sup>*</sup>As of the 2012 release, SystemVerilog added a multiple inheritance approach inspired/borrowed/similar-to Java's approach to the issue, by adding `interface class` and `implements`. However not all the major simulator vendor haven't implemented the improvement. I'm guessing UVM will eventually be overhauled and utilizes these features after simulator support for this feature is mainstream.*